# Check if an Object is in a ManyToMany Collection without fetch and iterate through all collection

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have three entities:

```
User (id, name, organizations[], ...)

Organization (id, name, plants[], ...)

Plant (id, name ...)
```

User.organizations and Organization.plants are ManyToMany FetchType.LAZY associations

Now, i have a "plant" and a "user" object. i would like to know if the plant object is in the plant collection of one (or more) of the organizations associated to the user.

Is it possible using JPA API, or at least Hibernate, to do that without fetching all collections, and without custom query ?

If, for example, a user has 2000 organizations and each can contains 1000 plants, it could be a real performance killer to iterate through collections.

Comment: Why would you even think of loading into memory and iterating when you can do a JPQL query for all Users that have some Organizations which contains the specified Plant?

Comment: I think i'll go the JPQL/native sql way but i wondered if there was another way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all user objects that have organizations that have the particular plant, you can do JPQL like this

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.organizations o JOIN o.plants p WHERE p.id = :myPlantId
```

and then look through the users for the one you want. Alternatively again, you can constrain by the specific user

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.organizations o JOIN o.plants p WHERE u.id = :myUserId AND p.id :myPlantId
```

Comment: I'll do like that. Thank you for quick and great answer